# Search on multiple columns - Create where clause

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox, ado.net

friends

please if you have time to solve my problem 
i have many textbox in my form with one button and one datagridview 
i use this code to make the search

What if i want to perform a search using values from 2 or more text boxes. what if I typed in "r" in the Name text box then also typed "NY" in the city text box. I want to see the gridview give me the results of that.

that what i try to find and i didn't find anything

the code is working if i search in one textbox only

warm regards

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

if (txtCIVILIDD.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Tabl1 where  CIVILIDD = '" + txtCIVILIDD.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
else if (txtName_Arabic.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tabl1 where Name_Arabic like '%" + txtName_Arabic.Text + "%'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
else if (txtusername.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Tabl1 where  username = '" + txtusername.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
else if (comboBox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tabl1 where status = '" + comboBox1.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
else if (comboBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tabl1 where confirmation = '" + comboBox2.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
else if (CBgender.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tabl1 where gender like '%" + CBgender.Text + "%'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
else if (CBNATIONALITY.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tabl1 where NATIONALITY like '" + CBNATIONALITY.Text + "%'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
else if (comboBoxGovernorate.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tabl1 where Governorate = '" + comboBoxGovernorate.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
else if (comboBoxCity.Text.Length > 0)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tabl1 where City = '" + comboBoxCity.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

i try to solve my problem with this code bout i find  "SELECT * FROM tabl1 WHERE 1=1 ";
it return null to me

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    StringBuilder sqlcommand = "SELECT * FROM tabl1 WHERE 1=1 ";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CBgender.Text))
    {
        sqlcommand.Append(" and GENDER LIKE '%");
        sqlcommand.Append(CBgender.Text);
        sqlcommand.Append("%'");
    }
    // repeat for other textbox fields

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

[my search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCMgy.png)

Comment: You should learn how to use SQL parameters - gluing data into string to make queries has not been the correct way for a very long time.  Then, rather than rebuilding your datasource, just use a DataView or RowFilter.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow the code is working with me when i search i one textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches. The first uses @WelcomeOverflows's suggestion which is to use the `RowFilter` property of the `DataTable`. The advantage of doing so is that you only have to perform one database query and the filtering is handled client side. However, it isn't possible to protect `RowFilter` from SQL injection easily (but while you can still potentially subvert the filtering intention, the damage you can do on a disconnected data source is limited). Also if the dataset is enormous, it might not be desirable to pull back the entire dataset at once and keep it in memory.

```
// call upon startup to get all the data one time
private void GetData()
{
    DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDatabase"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tabl1", connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
        adapter.Fill(dataSource);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
    }
}

// create a filter for the given field in the database and our control
private string CreateFilter(string fieldName, Control userInputControl, bool exactMatch)
{
    string searchValue = null;
    if (userInputControl is TextBox) searchValue = ((TextBox)userInputControl).Text;
    if (userInputControl is ComboBox) searchValue = ((ComboBox)userInputControl).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue)) return null;
    if (exactMatch)
        return String.Format("{0}='{1}'", fieldName, searchValue);
    return String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", fieldName, searchValue);
}

// set the filter on our data grid view
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var filterConditions = new[] {
        CreateFilter("Name_Arabic", txtName_Arabic, false),
        CreateFilter("gender", CBgender, false),
        CreateFilter("CIVILIDD", txtCIVILIDD, true),
        CreateFilter("NATIONALITY", cbNationality, false)
        // etc.
    };

    var dataSource = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
    if (!filterConditions.Any(a => a != null))
    {
        dataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
        return;
    }

    dataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = filterConditions
        .Where(a => a != null)
        .Aggregate((filter1, filter2) => String.Format("{0} AND {1}", filter1, filter2));
}
```

Second approach is to filter directly in the database query, using SQL parameters to avoid SQL injection.

```
private string CreateSqlFilter(string fieldName, Control userInputControl, SqlCommand command, bool exactMatch)
{
    string searchValue = null;
    if (userInputControl is TextBox) searchValue = ((TextBox)userInputControl).Text;
    if (userInputControl is ComboBox) searchValue = ((ComboBox)userInputControl).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue)) return null;

    if (exactMatch)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName, searchValue));
        return fieldName + " = @" + fieldName;
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + fieldName, "%" + searchValue + "%"));
        return fieldName + " LIKE @" + fieldName;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand();

    var filterConditions = new[] {
        CreateSqlFilter("Name_Arabic", txtName_Arabic, selectCommand, false),
        CreateSqlFilter("gender", CBgender, selectCommand, false),
        CreateSqlFilter("CIVILIDD", txtCIVILIDD, selectCommand, true),
        CreateSqlFilter("NATIONALITY", cbNationality, selectCommand, false)
        // etc.
    };

    string filterCondition = filterConditions.Any(a => a != null) ? filterConditions.Where(a => a != null).Aggregate((filter1, filter2) => String.Format("{0} AND {1}", filter1, filter2)) : (string)null;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDatabase"].ConnectionString))
    {
        selectCommand.Connection = connection;
        selectCommand.CommandText = filterCondition == null ? "SELECT * FROM tabl1" : "SELECT * FROM tabl1 WHERE " + filterCondition;
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
        DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dataSource);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: @steve16351 if i want to add more the 2 filter what should i do ??

Comment: The example already AND's four conditions and is extendable, what do you mean?

Comment: @steve16351 that you mean any textbox i will bout it will work ??

Comment: Yes, any combo box or text box you add to the `filterConditions` array in the same way as the others in the example will be used to build the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Create `StringBuilder` object:

```
StringBuilder sqlcommand = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM tabl1 WHERE 1=1");
```

Comment: when i test it ( it return null )

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parametrized query which considers parameters having null values as neutral in search. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE 
    (Id = @Id OR Id IS NULL) AND
    (Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' OR @Name IS NULL) AND
    (Price = @Price OR @Price IS NULL)
```

This way, if you pass `NULL` for any of the parameters, that parameter will not be considered in search.

Also as a side note, it prevents SQL Injection, by using parameters.

**Example**

The following example assumes you have a table called `Product`, having a column named `Id` as `INT`, `Name` as `NVARCHAR(100)` and `Price` as `INT`.

Then to load data, create the following method:

```
public DataTable GetData(int? id, string name, int? price)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var commandText = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE " +
        "(Id = @Id OR @Id is NULL) AND " +
        "(Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' OR @Name IS NULL) AND " +
        "(Price = @Price OR @Price IS NULL)";
    var connectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SampleDb;Integrated Security=True";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
            (object)id ?? DBNull.Value;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = 
            (object)name ?? DBNull.Value;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
            (object)price ?? DBNull.Value;
        using (var datAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            datAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

To get values from `TextBox` controls and pass to `GetData`, you can use the following code:

```
var id = int.TryParse(idTextBox.Text, out var tempId) ? tempId : default(int?);
var name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameTextBox.Text)?null:nameTextBox.Text;
var price = int.TryParse(priceTextBox.Text, out var priceId) ? priceId : default(int?);
```

Then to get data:

```
var data = GetData(id, name, price);
```